# Make tree structure for chessGames

Tags: class, tree, nodes, chess, stockfish

I want to make a Tree structure that shows my data from a number of chessGames. I dont want to use any libraries

The Node class is who has the turn and which move number it is. So there will be one node that is 1 White, and one that is 1 Black.

The Branch class is the children of the nodeclass that contains the exact move that was playes and then whos turn it is.

The moves from each game is stored in a string like this:

1. f4  d5  2. b3  Bg4  3. Bb2 Nc6  4. h3  Bh5  5. g4 Bg6  6. Nf3  h5  7. g5 e6  8. e3  Nge7  9. Bb5 a6  10. Bxc6+  Nxc6 11. d3  Qe7  12.Qe2  O-O-O  13. Qf2  f6  14. Nh4  Bf7  15. gxf6  gxf6  16. Nc3  Qe8  17. O-O-O  e5 18. Rdf1  Be6 19. f5  Bf7  20. Kb1  Rg8  21. Rhg1  Rxg1  22. Rxg1  Bc5  23. Ng6 b6  24. Na4  Bd6 25. Nc3  Bc5  26.Bc1  Qd7  27. Qf3 Kb8  28. Qxh5  Nb4  29. Na4  Bd6  30. Qg4  Qc6  31. Qg2  b5  32. Nb2  Qb6  33. Bd2 Bc5  34. c3  Nc6 35. d4  Bd6  36. h4 b4  37. dxe5 Nxe5  38. cxb4  d4  39. e4  d3  40. Rd1  Nc6  41. h5  Bxb4  42. Bc1  d2  43. Bxd2 Ba3  44. Qe2 Kb7  45. Bc1  Bxb2  46. Kxb2  Rxd1  47. Qxd1  Qf2+  48. Qd2  Qg1  49. h6  Bxg6  50. fxg6 1-0

This is my code so far:

```
class Node: 
def __init__(self, moveNr, color):
    self.moveNr = moveNr
    self.color = color
    self.branches = []

def addNewBranch(self,branch):
    for b in self.branches:
        if b.move == branch.move: 
            return
    self.branches.append(branch)
    return 
        


class Branch:
   def __init__(self, move):
       self.move = move 
       self.nextMove = None

   def setNextMove(self, nextMove):
       self.nextMove = nextMove

   def getNextMove(self):
       return self.nextMove

def getMoveDict(string1):
       moves_dict = {}
       moves = string1.split()
       for i in range(0, len(moves), 3):
          if i+2 < len(moves):
             key = moves[i].split('.')[0]
             value = (moves[i+1], moves[i+2])
             moves_dict[key] = value
       return moves_dict

 def makeTreeMoves(dict, tree):
   nodeList = []
   branchList = []
   for key in dict:
       node1 = Node(key, "white")
       node2 = Node(key, "black")
       nodeList.append(node1)
       nodeList.append(node2)
       tree.addTreeNode(node1)
       tree.addTreeNode(node2)

       branch1 = Branch(dict[key][0]) 
       branch2 = Branch(dict[key][1])
       branchList.append(branch1)
       branchList.append(branch2)
       tree.addTreeBranch(branch1)
       tree.addTreeBranch(branch2)

       node1.addNewBranch(branch1) 
       node2.addNewBranch(branch2)

   for x in range(len(nodeList)):
       if x == len(nodeList)-1:
          return
       branchList[x].setNextMove(nodeList[x+1])

class Tree: 
   def __init__(self):
       self.nodes = []
       self.branches = []

   def addTreeNode(self, node):
       self.nodes.append(node)

   def addTreeBranch(self, branch): 
       self.branches.append(branch)
```

But i think i may be on the wrong path? How should i make my tree structure and how do i add the nodes and branches(also nodes in tree) into the tree and making sure that i can follow the tree and see where a branch splits(where to similar games becomes different?

Comment: What do you expect from the tree? What's the purpose of storing all nodes and branches in the Tree instance. Do you have use cases where you will access the `branches` list and search for something? Can you provide examples of input and output scenarios?

Comment: @trincot: 

I want to somehow store the nodes and branches so that i can 1. vizualize the tree using graphviz. I also want to be able to Design functions to print an opening tree at a given depth, i.e. number of 1/2 moves.
The idea here is to get the number of games won by white pieces, by black pieces and
the number of games that ended up in a draw in each opening. Design functions to
insert your drawing in the report.

And design functions to parse a data base file such as "Stockfish 15 64-bit.commented.[2600].pgn.gz " and load it into an opening tree

Comment: *"Design functions to insert your drawing in the report."*: what does that mean?

Comment: *"file such as "Stockfish 15 64-bit.commented.[2600].pgn.gz"*: I have no idea what that file is.

Comment: @trincot the drawing is the pdf that graphviz produces when you add nodes and edges. The Stockfish" file is a pgn file that cpontains 2600 games played by the chessAI StockFish. This is where we get our moves-strings from. I know how to do this, but i am unsure of how to store these moves from all the games in a tree -structure using nodes and branches

Comment: *"I know how to do this"*: did you notice how your example string is not correctly converted to a dict? The move 12.Qe2 is lost.

Comment: Anyway, this question is too open-ended. Try to focus on a *specific* problem you have.